# How do I close scanner during sleep method?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, sleep

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
public class Lab1 {

    public static void main(String args[]) 
    throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("Please enter your first name.");
        String name;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        name = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println(name);
        Thread.sleep(1200); 
    } 
}
```

Because the scanner is still open, users can type during the pause. It doesn't crash the program, but I still want to be able to close the scanner and be able to reopen it later on in the code.

Comment: Try : `sc.close()`. Also what does *"Because the scanner is still open, users can type during the pause."* mean?

Comment: Do you want to close and use scanner again after sleep? like `Thread.sleep(1200);sc.close(); sc.nextLine() ` did I understand correctly?

Comment: You can’t.  Even native programs have no way to stop this;  for instance, if you do `cat verylongfile.txt` in Unix/Linux, you can type while the command is printing, and your typed characters will appear amid the program’s output.  If you want more control, create a graphical user interface using JavaFX or Swing, rather than relying on the console.

Comment: You can use something like jcurses to do it, but you're writing a TUI (textual user interface) if you do.

Answer (score 1):

As of Java 7, `Scanner` implements `AutoCloseable`, so you can use try-with-resources to close it automatically:

```
String name;
try (Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in)) {
    name = in.nextLine();
}
System.out.println(name);
```

Comment: How do you then deal with _be able to reopen it later_?